# Stripe Connect Application Fee Discrepancy

Tags: c#, .net, stripe.net

So, I'm not sure if this is a coding error or a misunderstanding of the Stripe Connect process on my part, but I'm trying to make a charge using the Stripe .NET wrapper. My code is below:

```
int chargeAmount = 2014;
int appFee = 1986;

var stripeChargeOption = new StripeChargeCreateOptions()
                            {
                                AmountInCents = chargeAmount,
                                Currency = "cad",
                                Card = stripeToken.Id,
                                Description = "Your Purchase with Coupons4Giving - " + info.Merchant.Name,
                                ApplicationFeeInCents = appFee
                            };
                            var response = stripeService.Create(stripeChargeOption);
```

The problem is when I go and look at what's actually gone through, the values differ from what I specify in this call. On Stripe's side, it shows the Application Fee as being $19.26 (which is $20.14 minus Stripe's fee of 2.9% + $0.30).

Can anyone tell me why my Application Fee is $20.14 instead of the $19.86 I've attempted to specify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Stripe takes the Application Fee out of the total Charge. My mistake was thinking that it added the fee to the charge, thus a $2 charge with a $2.25 fee won't work (the fee gets dropped to $2, as that's the most it can be).